# How to add escape sequence to String variables?

Tags: ruby

When adding one escape character to string and printing the output does not replace escape character in the output string

```
indent = '\t'
message = 'Hello there'
message = "#{indent} #{message}"
puts(message)
```

From the above code output printed is as below

```
\t Hello there
```

What is wrong with this code? What is the way to achieve the intended output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `"` instead `'` in:

```
indent = '\t'
```

Look:

```
irb(main):001:0> indent = '\t'
=> "\\t"
irb(main):002:0> indent = "\t"
=> "\t"
```